# threejs: Why can the light pass through the plane?

Tags: three.js

[image]

Why can the light pass through the plane?

Comment: Does your lightsource have shadows?

Comment: Yes it has a shadow

Comment: Why does your question have no code in it?

Comment: @pailhead He's probably working with the [editor](https://threejs.org/editor/)

Comment: how should the answers be written then "click checkbox bar in table foo.."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, shadow mapping uses back faces.

Planes only have 1 (front) face. To make shadows work with plane, try to enable front face shadows by disabling `renderReverseSided` :

```
renderer.shadowMap.enable = true;
renderer.shadowMap.renderReverseSided = false;
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42Lrt3j4/) and [this issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1637).

Answer (score 1):

WebGL does not have light occlusion implemented by default. As such, all surfaces visible by the light source will be lit.